# Wordpress front page issue

Tags: wordpress

I currently have a custom template page which I have set through the 'reading' section in wordpress settings. I need to change the front page of the site, so I select my new custom template page in the 'reading' section and apply it.

However, although it loads the correct CSS styles etc, it seems to be loading the html content of my previous front page. It seems to do this no matter what custom template I select for my front page!

Any ideas? Help!!!

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an issue related to your cache not being cleared. Try clearing your browser cache by pressing F5, if that doesn't fix it the follow below.

Do you have any caching plugins on Wordpress (you may also have a server cache)? For example WP Super Cache or W3 Total Cache (there are many more caching plugins)?

If you do then you will have to clear the cache.

Comment: Thanks for replying.
I tried clearing the cache. Also tried deactivating every plug-in, but the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the problem. There was a file called front_page.php which was overriding whatever page I set. All I had to do was delete this file